# Error : pod package : 'Unable to find a specification for 'PRIVATE FRAMEWORK' depended upon by this

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, package, cocoapods

I apologize for my poor English.

I want to create my own framework using `'cocoapods-packager'`.

It needs dependencies with those in private repository of GitHub.

Each file is described as follows.

**・Podfile**
 pod 'PRIVATEREPO', :git => 'https://github.com/PRIVATEREPO.git'

**・FRAMEWORK.podspec**
 s.dependency "RIVATEREPO"

The following error will occur when executed.

```
$ pod package FRAMEWORK.podspec --dynamic --spec-sources=https://github.com/FRAMEWORK.git --verbose`

Resolving dependencies of 
**[!] Unable to find a specification for `PRIVATEREPO` depended upon by `FRAMEWORK`**

Is ~/.cocoapods/repos/ related?
```

Do you know the cause？

Thank